# Is "figure something out" natural here?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

Is "figure something out" perfectly natural in the context below?

A: Can I see you sometime next week or are you too busy?

B: No, I guess we can figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

*Person A* would like to know if *Person B* will be too busy to get together in the next week.

*Person B* says he/she is not too busy, and because he/she is not, he/she supposes that a time, date and meeting place (the **details** of the meeting) can be arranged between the two of them, presumably later that day.

*I guess we can figure something out* is a perfectly natural way to express the above. Hope this helps!